# Taking two lists and printing specific characters based on their postition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to work out how to take two lists (firstname,lastname) and printing the first 2 characters from one list and 1st character from the other and joining them during a print.

Example

```
firstname = ("John", "Jake")
lastname = ("Smith, "Jones")
```

I'd like the output to look like this

```
Smj
Joj
```

So print first 2 characters from lastname and 1st character from firstname but joined together.

I have tried firstly by creating one list of them both, then from two lists and finally I tried doing it using a dictionary (two lists into dictionary).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
firstname = ("John", "Jake") 
lastname = ("Smith", "Jones")
result = []
for firstname, lastname in zip(firstname, lastname):
    result.append('{}{}'.format(lastname[:2], firstname[0].lower()))
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
firstnames = ("John", "Jake") 
lastnames = ("Smith", "Jones")

for f, l in zip(firstnames, lastnames):
    print l[:2] + f[:1].lower()
```

Prints to console:

```
Smj
Joj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension

```
>>> [ lastname[i][:2] + firstname[i][0].lower() for i in range(len(firstname))]
['Smj', 'Joj']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) für zipping last_names and first_names to one data structure and then use one simple line of functional programming ([map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) & [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)):

```
first_names = ["John", "Jake"]
last_names = ["Smith", "Jones"]

map(lambda x: x[0][:2] + x[1][0].lower(), zip(last_names, first_names))
```

[map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) iterates over a data structure and processes a function on each element. In our case the function `lambda x: x[0][:2] + x[1][0].lower()`. Lambda functions are working like normal functions but they are anonymous. The argument x represents on single tuple out of `zip(last_names, first_names)`. Then `x[0][:2]` extracts the first two characters out of the last name and `x[1][0].lower()` takes the first character of the first name and converts it to lower case.

The **output** is a list representation of your expected result:

```
>> ['Smj', 'Joj']
```

This solution is Python 2.X only, because map returns a list. In Python 3.X you would have to add an additional list() to convert the returned map object to a list representation. Then the result would be the same.